# Jest Shallow Component Testing Error "Cannot read property of undefined"

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, enzyme

I want to shallow render a component and check to see if it doesn't crash. The docs tells me that shallow rendering doesn't go any deeper into child components.

I have this code:

```
it("Renders the Compare landing page without crashing", () => {
  shallow(<Compare />);
});
```

The `Compare` Component contains the following code:

```
<Fragment>
        <Sidenav params={this.props.match.params.gamerId} />
        <div className="content-area">
          <SearchBar
            updateSearch={this.updateSearch}
            placeholder={"Filter by Friends"}
          />
          <div className="friends">
            {filteredFriends.map((friend, key) => {
              return (
                <Friend
                  name={friend}
                  key={key}
                  index={key}
                  goToCompare={this.goToCompare}
                />
              );
            })}
          </div>
        </div>
</Fragment>
```

The test throws the following error:

[image: Screenshot of error]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](https://i.gyazo.com/0b190bae8cb3a0b51665382321077bc7.png))</sub>

Shouldn't the test just ignore the `<SideNav />`, what am I missing here?

Comment: No, the test won't ignore the `<SideNav/>`. You need to pass a value to the `match` prop.

Answer (score 0):

My solution might not be the best, but this is what I do:

I create a mock function for the match:

```
import {match} from 'react-router';

export function mockedMatch<P = void>(params?: P): match<P> {
    return {
        params,
        isExact: true,
        path: 'lorem/ipsum',
        url: 'dummyUrl',
    };
}
```

And then pass this mock to the component while testing:

```
shallow(<Compare match={mockedMatch({gamerId: 'test-id'})} />);
```

My solution is in TypeScript, but you can remove the types and it will work in your case as well.